# Why is my NSDate timezone incorrect?

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here's the code:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];

NSDate* newTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-10-19T12:22:07Z"];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HHmm"];

NSString* finalTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newTime];
```

The problem:

I'm in Toronto (EST, GMT-5). My final time SHOULD show 0722, I'm seeing 0822. Inspecting the objects I can see that newTime is '2011-10-19 08:22:07 EDT'. I'm not sure why that happens but it persists onto the finalTime string despite setting the dateFormatter time zone to systemTimeZone. I assume systemTimeZone is EDT then? Any insight into why this happens or how I can correct it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. Don't set the timezone on the date formatter. And then remove the quotes around the `Z` in the format string. This will allow the date formatter to determine the timezone from the actual date string.
2. The output of `0822` is correct for your system timezone because you were on day light savings time on October 19th. On that date you were GMT-4, not GMT-5. In Canada, in 2011, DST ended on November 6th.

Comment: Ok, what you say makes sense. I've removed the timezone setting and the quotes and understand that the EDT is based on the timezone for the date string and not what I currently am at.

That said, I still need to display it in my current timezone, so I need to see it in EST (0722). I feel like I've tried 50 combinations of things and none has yielded 0722.

Comment: It is using your timezone. In your timezone, 1222 Z on October 19, 2011. is 0822. What you are trying to do doesn't really make much sense. It seems are trying to force a time from one date to the same time on the current date. What do you wish to see when this code run in another month when you are back on DST?

Comment: Correct, but presently, in EST, I'm looking to see it as 0722.

Comment: But it wasn't EST on October 19, 2011. It was EDT. Why do you want to show a timestamp with a different DST value than it had at the time?

Answer (score 2):

You're currently in Toronto EST. This time report you are getting back is showing EDT. Which is Eastern Daylight Time. Make sure you subtract an hour for daylight savings time since it's EDT not EST.

---

I'm out right now so I can't test this code but I think this should work:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeZone *currentZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; 

if ([currentZone isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:currentDate]) {
   //adjust the time by 1 hour here
}
```

Comment: Should systemTimeZone not know that I'm in EST? In the summer we'll switch to EDT and it'll work just fine. If I subtract an hour now, come spring when we switch it'll be one hour behind.

Comment: @r0ddy If you use the code I put above you will only adjust by 1 hour during Daylight savings time, and when the date input is no longer daylight savings time the hour will not modify. Put the adjusting code inside the conditional statement.

Comment: @r0ddy The code above grabs the current date, you can use a different NSDate if you'd like.. just (cast *) it.